# i18next jquery translate element inside another element

Tags: jquery, translation, i18next

how would I go about translating 2 elements when one is inside the other? This is an example of what I mean:

```
<p data-i18n="alreadyregistered" ><a href="login.php" data-i18n="login"></a></p>
```

On this one the outer p gets translated properly but the a doesn't even appear.

```
<p data-i18n="alreadyregistered" data-i18n-target=".inner"><a href="login.php" class="inner" data-i18n="login"></a></p>
```

On this one it's the other way around.

How do I make them both translate?

EDIT:
expected output is that the p and a both get my translations and then display the text. this is what I have for both i18n translations: for estonian `alreadyregistered: "Kasutaja juba olemas?", login: "Logi sisse",` and for english `alreadyregistered: "Already have an account?", login: "Login",`

So it should display the first part as text and the second a part as a link according to what the user has chosen for their language.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @mplungjan tried to explain the output in the edit. Hope it clears something up but I don't really know how to explain it too well. The point is only one of the elements gets the property from i18n but I need them both to get theirs

Comment: But there is nothing in your examples that need translating